# How can I make objects fall at steady speed?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have two objects (same size, same geometry) falling from different heights; obviously the object in the higher position speed up and has a different behavior when hitting the ground, compared to the other object.

How can I keep the velocity constant at all times, until they hit the ground?

[image]

Comment: All object fall at the same weight, regardless of mass or size. The force that slows different objects down is friction.

Comment: Height, not weight...I could modify the damping value but I don't want to act on rigidbody dynamics; are there other methods to achieve the result?

Comment: Speed, not weight. Sorry.

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 you mean rate, not speed ... i.e. acceleration ( or rate of change of speed ).  The only thing that changes speed is a force, at or near a massive object this force will be the gravity.  Blender fakes gravity by default for earthlings.  To stop this you turn the gravity off in the scene properties.

Answer (score 3):

Set gravity to 0 and give them both same initial velocity

(also make sure to give em a lot of solver iterations/steps per second so physics calculate nicely)
[image]

Comment: how can I do this showed in the panel below the animation? I can't change the interpolation mode.

Comment: Are you refeering to Graph Editor?    If that's so, I changed interpolation by selecting the keyframes and pressing T

Answer (score 0):

Turn off GRAVITY (no gravity at all), than add WIND with say value of 100 (with an arrow pointing down). All object will fall at constant rate (with no acceleration).